# How to add a button adjacent to Update cart button in Magento2.1 cart page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layout

How can I add a custom button adjacent to Update Shopping car button in Magento2.1?

[image]

I created a file `checkout_cart_index.xml` with following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block template="Namespace_Module::custom/mybutton.phtml" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="my.button" as="my.button"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it shows button below the ***Apply Discount Code***  section.

Is it possible to achieve this without overriding `cart/form.phtml`

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
</block>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the button adjacent to other button then we have to override **form.phtml** file. Which is used in the core checkout module of magento2

```
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\layout\checkout_cart_index.xml
```

check for

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="cart/form.phtml" after="cart.summary">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
</block>
```

So we need to create `checkout_cart_index.xml` file in our custom module and set a custom template consisting core code as well as our on button code.

Answer (score 1):

Following is code without overriding form.html.

view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Myvendor\Mymodule\Block\Cart\Button" name="se.emailcart" template="Myvendor_Mymodule::cart/button.phtml" after="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

view/frontend/templates/cart/button.phtml

```
<script data-role="se_show_buttom-tmpl" type="text/x-magento-template">
    <button name="action_button_link"
            class="action_button_link"
            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Some Button')) ?>">
        <span><?= __('Some Button') ?></span>
    </button>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
require(
    ['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        var template = $('[data-role=se_show_buttom-tmpl]') ;

        if (template.length) {
            $('.cart.main.actions').prepend(template.html().trim());
        }
    }
);
</script>
```